# Vectorization of a function dependent on 2 arrays in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize a function that consist of a loop.

The original function is:

```
def error(X, Y, m, c):
    total = 0
    for i in range(20):
        total += (Y[i]-(m*X[i]+c))**2
    return total
```

I've tried the following but It doesn't work:

```
def error(X, Y, m, c):
    errorVector = np.array([(y-(m*x+c))**2 for (x,y) in (X,Y)])
    total = errorVector.sum()
    return total
```

How can I vectorize the function?

Comment: Can you post, minimal, examples of `X,Y,m,c`?

Comment: X and Y are numpy arrays such as X = np.array([x for x in range(20)]). m and c are coefficients to the linear equation m*x+c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement @jpp's answer (which assumes that `X` and `Y` both have the shape `(20, ...)`), here's an exact equivalent of your `error` function:

```py
def error(X, Y, m, c):
  return np.sum((Y[:20] - (m * X[:20] + c)) ** 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way, assuming `X` and `Y` have first dimension of length 20.

```
def error(X, Y, m, c):
    total = 0
    for i in range(20):
        total += (Y[i]-(m*X[i]+c))**2
    return total 

def error_vec(X, Y, m, c):
    return np.sum((Y - (m*X + c))**2)

m, c = 3, 4
X = np.arange(20)
Y = np.arange(20)

assert error(X, Y, m, c) == error_vec(X, Y, m, c)
```